# Keep the value of an argument after being used in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm learning Javascript and I'm doing a little program that calculates the waiter tips based on the amount of your bill and the total you have to pay (bill + tip). This return 2 arrays, the first one with the tips by bill and the second with the total to pay.

Here is the code:

```js
var myBillsArray = [];
var numberOfBills = parseInt(prompt('Please enter the number of bills.'));
for(i=0; i<numberOfBills; i++){
  myBillsArray[i] = parseInt(prompt(`Insert your bill number ${i+1}`));
}
holidayBills(myBillsArray);

function holidayBills(billsArrays){
  var tipsArray =  [];
  var finalBillArray = [];  

  tipsArray = calculateTips(billsArrays);
  finalBillArray = calculateFinalBill(myBillsArray, tipsArray);

  console.log(tipsArray);
  console.log(finalBillArray);
}

function calculateTips(arrayOfBills){
  for(i=0; i<arrayOfBills.length; i++){
    if(arrayOfBills[i] < 50){
      arrayOfBills[i] *= 0.20;
    }else if(arrayOfBills[i] >= 50 && arrayOfBills[i] < 200){
      arrayOfBills[i] *= 0.15;
    }else{
      arrayOfBills[i] *= 0.10;
    }
  }
  return arrayOfBills;
}
function calculateFinalBill(arrayOfBills, arrayOfTips){
  var finalBill = [];
  for(i=0; i<arrayOfBills.length; i++){
    finalBill[i] = arrayOfBills[i] + arrayOfTips[i];
  }
  return finalBill;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JonathanSosa/6ejudpv0/3/)

But the only issue that I'm having is that when I do the addition of the bill + tip, the bill value is the same that the tip value. I think it's a matter of scope, but I don't know where.

If you're wondering why I'm using `var` instead of `let` it's because the exercise asks me to.

Comment: finalBillArray = calculateFinalBill(billsArrays, tipsArray);
 instead of 
finalBillArray = calculateFinalBill(myBillsArray, tipsArray); //?

Comment: Other than that it works fine for me (even the above will work but i dont think its what you meant)

Comment: I meant, if you enter 2 bills [1000, 2000], tips will be [100, 200] and the total bill will be [1100, 2200], but I get in total bill [200,400]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that when you do calculate the tips, you are modifying the elements of `myBillsArray`. This happens because arrays are passed by reference in JavaScript, meaning that `arrayOfBills` is not a new array containing all the elements of `myBillsArray`, it's the same array. So any modifications you make to it will show up when you refer to it as `myBillsArray`.

To fix this problem you could do this:

```
function calculateTips(arrayOfBills){
  var myTips = [];
  for(i=0; i<arrayOfBills.length; i++){
    if(arrayOfBills[i] < 50){
      myTips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.20;
    }else if(arrayOfBills[i] >= 50 && arrayOfBills[i] < 200){
      myTips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.15;
    }else{
      myTips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.10;
    }
  }
  return myTips;
}
```

Comment: It's done, thank you so much. What I had done was to create an array in that function and copy the arrayOfBills to that new array, but it didn't work also. Anyway, thanks a lot @nick.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the calculateTips function to following. Use a new array to keep result of the function

```
function calculateTips(arrayOfBills){
    var tips = []

  for(i=0; i<arrayOfBills.length; i++){
    if(arrayOfBills[i] < 50){
      tips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.20;
    }else if(arrayOfBills[i] >= 50 && arrayOfBills[i] < 200){
      tips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.15;
    }else{
      tips[i] = arrayOfBills[i] * 0.10;
    }
  }
  return tips;
}
```

Comment: You can also use array functions to make your code cleaner and shorter. (array map function, array reduce function etc.)

Comment: I'll do, I mean I'm starting with Javascript, once I lean the basics I'll jump to the functions :D